# Excel : Distribute Percentage evenly for a range of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers, range, percentage

I have a range of numbers from 1, all the way to 1172.
I would like to evenly distribute percentage from 1% to 100% for 1 to 1172.
Number 1172 must be 100%. Number 1 must be 1%. The percentage does not have to decimal places, whole numbers is fine.
1% to 99% to be distributed from 1 to 1171 number range.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this on Excel? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let the first number be 0.01 and last number 11.72. Fill the series in increment  of 0.000853 i.e. (1/1172) giving 1,1.0853,1.1706. Multiply with 100 to get percentages . Use `INT` Function to get full numbers like 1, 2 3 etc.

Comment: hi @skkakkar, that works amazingly. thank you so much

Comment: I have corrected the increment value after review, please look into it and if it meets your requirement, please accept my answer by ticking arrow beneath lower triangle on left side of the posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let the first number be 0.01 and last number 11.72. Fill the series in increment of 0.0008455 as shown in the snapshot. Multiply with 100 to get percentages . Use `INT` Function to get full numbers like 1, 2 3 etc. ,if desired.

[image]